# Cisco UCP Web Service Issue AuthenticateUser

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, cisco

**Update:** This issue has been resolved.  I was trying to authenticate various admin accounts which apparently are in a separate database than the user accounts this service talks to.  I used a generic user account that I created in CISCO and the web service calls worked great!

*I would like to thank @Yahia for the recommendation on running Fiddler also!*

I've been reading over the **CICCO UCP Web Service** [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5.1/sdk/ucp.html#wp1054873) for days now.  I'm able to talk to the one web service on the box, with proper credentials and everything works fine; however, with the **UCP Service**, I get an *error*...  SoapUI seems to understand the WSDL file, and I'm able to send a request to the endpoint but I get an authentication error, below.

I use the same username and password to login to the ACS Portal so the account is not expired.  I'm pretty much lost on this one and at the mercy of CICSO tech support.  **Any and all ideas are welcome!**

**SOAP Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:authenticateUserResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/">
         <authenticateUserReturn href="#id0"/>
      </ns1:authenticateUserResponse>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:ResponseType" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/">
         <errors soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
            <errors xsi:type="xsd:string">Credentials are incorrect.</errors>
         </errors>
         <status href="#id1"/>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:StatusCodeType" xmlns:ns3="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">failure</multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Soap Envelope:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:authenticateUser soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <userName xsi:type="xsd:string">myusername</userName>
    <password xsi:type="xsd:string">mypassword</password>
      </ser:authenticateUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**And the WSDL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
xmlns:impl="http://www.cisco.com/wsdl.service"
xmlns:intf="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:documentation>Copyright (c) 2007, 2009 Cisco Systems, Inc.
  WSDL Service Interface for ACS5.1 User Change Password interface
  (UCP) This WSDL document defines the publication API calls for
  interacting with the ACS UCP service.</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType"
            wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
      <simpleType name="StatusCodeType">
        <restriction base="string">
          <enumeration value="success" />
          <enumeration value="failure" />
        </restriction>
      </simpleType>
      <complexType name="ResponseType">
        <sequence>
          <element name="errors" nillable="true"
          type="intf:ArrayOf_xsd_string" />
          <element name="status" nillable="false"
          type="intf:StatusCodeType" />
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="changeUserPassRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="userName" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="oldPassword" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="newPassword" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="authenticateUserRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="userName" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="changeUserPassResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="changeUserPassReturn"
    type="intf:ResponseType" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="authenticateUserResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="authenticateUserReturn"
    type="intf:ResponseType" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="UCP">
    <wsdl:operation name="authenticateUser"
    parameterOrder="userName password">
      <wsdl:input message="intf:authenticateUserRequest"
      name="authenticateUserRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="intf:authenticateUserResponse"
      name="authenticateUserResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="changeUserPass"
    parameterOrder="userName oldPassword newPassword">
      <wsdl:input message="intf:changeUserPassRequest"
      name="changeUserPassRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="intf:changeUserPassResponse"
      name="changeUserPassResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="UCP" type="intf:UCP">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc"
    transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="authenticateUser">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <wsdl:input name="authenticateUserRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
        use="encoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="authenticateUserResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
        use="encoded" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="changeUserPass">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <wsdl:input name="changeUserPassRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
        use="encoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="changeUserPassResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        namespace="http://cisco.com/nm/acs/mgmt/ucp/service/"
        use="encoded" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="UCPService">
    <wsdl:port binding="intf:UCP" name="UCP">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="https://localhost/PI/services/UCP/" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: do you have any client available which is successfully using this webservice ? if yes, then you can "listen in" with WireShark and/or Fiddler and then check the difference between what they send over wire and what you send...

Comment: Excellent recommendation, @Yahia.  I used FireFox with LiveHTTPHeaders and Tamper Data to see what was going across the wire from the Cisco portal.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they are using their own web service, but java instead.  Perhaps the Cisco consultant will write some example web service code and I can test that also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: This issue has been resolved. I was trying to authenticate various admin accounts which apparently are in a separate database than the user accounts this service talks to. I used a generic user account that I created in CISCO and the web service calls worked great!

I would like to thank @Yahia for the recommendation on running Fiddler also!